# Is it possible to register a grunt task with a variable name?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a couple project that I would like to use the same template for.
This has caused me to want to prefix my grunt tasks which I register with a project abbreviation vs a script that has to generate these project specific grunt files.

Is this possible to do?

ex.
from -

```
grunt.registerTask('proj-build','Builds my app.',['build']);
```

to -

```
grunt.registerTask(<PROJECT NAME>'-build','Builds my app.',['build']);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gruntfile.js is just simple JavaScript file so you can write any code you need:

```
var project_name = get_my_project_name();
grunt.registerTask(project_name + '-build','Builds my app.',['build']);
```